# How do I select distinct json columns?

Tags: postgresql, duplication, json, postgis

I have over 10,000 geojson rows in a table. How do I go about selecting only distinct coordinates?

The data was imported from a csv file into PostgreSQL 9.5. The columns in the table are:

```
Trip Duration (seconds)
Start Time and Date
Stop Time and Date
Start Station Name
End Station Name
Station ID
Station Lat/Long
```

The imported contains I took the latitude and longitude columns and turned it into a geojson object:

```
update h set thestartgeom =  st_asgeojson(startstationgeom);
```

The column thestartgeom in the table is

```
  thestartgeom text;
```

The database contains 10,000+ lat/lng and other records. Some of the coordinates are duplicated. I am trying to eliminate all duplicates.

`startstationgeom` is a `geometry(POINT,4326)`.

Here is the geojson column:

```json
                    thestartgeom                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------

{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.6882247924805,-73.9793853759766]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7329139709473,-74.0071105957031]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7429084777832,-73.9770584106445]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7160568237305,-73.9919052124023]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7497177124023,-74.0029525756836]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7349281311035,-73.9920043945312]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7281455993652,-73.9902114868164]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.691650390625,-73.9999771118164]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7501983642578,-73.9909286499023]}
{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7503814697266,-73.9833908081055]}
```

Comment: Do you just want coordinates or whole rows with distinct coordinates? In the later case you need to define *which* row from a set of peers. Also, please *always* provide table definition and Postgres version.

Comment: So then just use that column like any other column to do exactly what you want. You're serializing that column to geojson, and you're not telling us why. It doesn't make sense. If I ask you how to `How do I select distinct json columns?`, but I'm generating the json columns from integers the question is *why are you doing that?* *Why not just use the integers?* You can just do `SELECT DISTINCT ON (startstationgeom), * FROM tbl` or whatever. Or see which points have duplicates, `SELECT startstationgeom, count(*) FROM tbl GROUP BY startstationgeom HAVING count(startstationgeom) > 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want PostGIS's [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html).

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson)
FROM tbl;
```

Should work to get the points. However may find this is faster... I'd be interested in seeing a benchmark. `ST_Union` will eliminate duplicate points and geometries too.

```
SELECT ST_Union(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson))
FROM tbl;
```

### Update

Is it faster, what advantages and disadvantages does this have?

- `DISTINCT` requires a `SORT`. faster to sort floats than strings.
- My `ST_Mem_Size(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(geojson))` shows 32 bytes (two floats).
- Not sure how much space the raw JSON takes, likely more than 32 bytes.
- Likely have to have these as `::geography` at some time.
- Processing the JSON and creating points is a one time cost but it may be significant.
- [`ST_GeomFromJSON`](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#geometry-objects) supports all geometry objects. Including `MultiPoints`.

### Update2

If you already got the type as `startstationgeom`, just do

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Union(startstationgeom)) FROM table
```

That will output only unique geometries.

Answer (score -1):

simple form of query is:

```
select
    max(id),
    jtext->>'coordinates' as coordinates

from t_json
GROUP BY coordinates
```

more information about JSON - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

just other form of same query:

```
select
    distinct
    jtext #>> '{coordinates,0}' as lat,
    jtext #>> '{coordinates,1}' as lon
from t_json
```

tyson and j_text - it name of table and json column in my example

first form allow return other columns, not only coordinates in distinct query

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your response. I get *HINT:  "co" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry* any suggestions?

Comment: PostGIS has a GeomJSON parser built in. I would use that, and let C do the lifting.

Comment: Welcome, and If it not coordinates, You also will look for other extensions ;)

Comment: @MichealC. - this is error from PostGIS, so need check - what the problem, or with Your query or with Your data